# How to achieve (approx) unit scaling of a non-linear diffusion (heat) equation with a wildly varying diffusion coefficient?

Tags: pde, diffusion, scaling

I have numerical issues with a poorly scaled one-dimensional non-linear diffusion equation in physical co-ordinates

$$ \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{t}}(x,t) = \frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}\left(D(u)  \frac{\partial{u}(x,t)}{\partial{x}}\right)$$

$$x \in (0,L),\  t \in (0,t_\text{f}) $$

with initial conditions 
$$u(x,0) = u_0(x)$$ and Double-Neumann Boundary Conditions 
$$D(u)\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}_{\Large\mid \normalsize{x=0}} = f(t); \quad D(u)\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}_{\Large\mid \normalsize{x=L}} = 0$$.

In numerically solving this PDE, I end up with convergence errors due to poor scaling of the problem with $u \approx \mathcal{O}(10^3)$, $x \approx \mathcal{O}(10^-6)$, and the most problematic of them all $D(u) \approx \mathcal{O}(10^{-12})\text{ to }\mathcal{O}(10^{-16}) $.

By applying standard scaling techniques $\bar{t} = \frac{t}{t_\text{c}}$, $\bar{x} = \frac{x}{x_\text{c}}$, $\bar{u} = \frac{u}{u_\text{c}}$, $\bar{D} = \frac{D}{D_\text{c}}$, and setting $x_\text{c} = L$, $D_\text{c} = D_{\max}$, $t_\text{c} = \frac{L^2}{D_{\max}}$ and $u_\text{c} = {u_{\max}}$, I was able to arrive at a better-scaled non-dimensionalised version of the PDE as

$$ \frac{\partial{\bar{u}}}{\partial{\bar{t}}}(\bar{x},\bar{t}) = \frac{\partial}{\partial{\bar{x}}}\left(\bar{D}(\bar{u})  \frac{\partial{\bar{u}}(\bar{x},\bar{t})}{\partial{\bar{x}}}\right)$$

in the unit interval $\bar{x} \in (0,1)$ with $\bar{u} \in (0,1)$. However, due to the 4 orders of magnitude variation in $\bar{D}$ as well as the poor resolution of its values, it doesn't look like the linear scaling $\bar{D} = \frac{D}{D_\text{max}}$ is the correct one to use.

Can someone please help to scale this PDE for better numerical conditioning?

Comment: Did you try changing the equation to log scale? Take $\phi = \log{(u)}$, so your diffusion equation becomes: $$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} = \exp{(\phi)} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (\exp{(\phi)} D(\phi) \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x})$$ The new diffusion coefficient would be: $$D^{'}(\phi) = \exp{(\phi)} D(\phi)$$ and it hopefully will balance the multiplication of very large numbers to very small numbers.

Comment: This formulation just makes the non-linearities much stronger without much gain.

Comment: How $f(t)$ behaves in time? Is it increasing or decreasing always or it oscillates somehow?

Comment: For now, I am happy to assume $f(t) = 1$, and scale my PDE properly. How about choosing something along the lines of logarithmic scaling for both the diffusion coefficient as well as the spatial variable $x$?

Comment: You **can't** assume $f(t) = 1$. Think about it physically. You are pumping mass into the system with the constant rate but on the other hand you blocked the other side of the domain by imposing zero flux boundary condition, it means at some point your system will be exploded cause you are pumping mass into the system and this mass keeps accumulating without any way to go out of your domain.

Comment: Yes. You are of course correct. For a few time-steps this is okay until the saturation point is reached. Later on, $f(t)$ becomes zero, $f(t) = -1$ etc. $f(t)$ is piecewise constant over $t$.

Comment: I think even at the very first time-steps, this problem is ill-posed and that's the reason for seeing some nonsense solutions probably. Also, having a nonlinear diffusion coefficient in the order of $10^{-12}$ is not that small to make your framework unstable necessarily. I think the main problem is that generally PDEs with only Neumann boundary conditions are unstable generally. At least for diffusion equation without any other mechanism of mass transport (e.g. convection, etc.), the problem is very much ill-posed by using two Neumann boundary conditions at the inlet and outlet.

Comment: How is $D(u)$ defined?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth  My linearly scaled $\bar{D}(\bar{u})$ in the scaled version of the PDE is $\bar{D}(\bar{u}) = 1944.0 \bar{u} - 566.0 e^\bar{u} - 1322.0 \sin(\bar{u}) + 151.0 \bar{u}^2 + 560.0$ with $\bar{u} \in (0,1)$ and $\bar{D} \in (0,1)$

Comment: @Krishna: But that means that $D(u)$ is zero if $u$ is zero. Do you have other ways to ensure that $u$ is bounded away from zero? You can't have a coefficient that goes to zero. It makes the problem ill-posed.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Yes. In fact, $\bar{u}$ does not go to zero. Although I have reported the scaling as $\bar{u} \in (0,1)$, $\bar{u}_\text{min} = 0.3 $ and $\bar{u}_\text{max} = 0.9 $

Comment: But in that case, $\bar D$ only varies between 8.1 and 10.2 or so. That seems like not very much of a variation to begin with.